# Uploadify IO Error 2038 for large images

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I am using jquery Uploadify to upload images in my application.
It is working fine earlier but in last few day i got reports the some image are not getting uploaded and it gives "IO Error".

In my analysis i figured out that it is causing issue when i tried to upload images larger than 100 - 120 kb.

Earlier it is working fine and uploading much larger images but now it stopped suddenly for larger images.

I am uploading single image at a time 
Any help ?